# access log apache and htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

is there any way to config htaccess to write to access-log file which is already handled by apache in syntax

```
 LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
```

Need to add more varibale to custom log but dont have access to apache ,

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No.

Documentation **clearly** says that `LogFormat` directive can **only** be used in Server Config and Virtual Host contexts. This is security restriction, otherwise if your site is hacked (e.g. attacker can create or modify your .htaccess) he will be able to see all requests to your site (the main point here is to protect your visitors even if you do not care about this aspect).

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_log_config.html#logformat